# An Optimization issue in Android

Tags: android, performance, android-listview, android-contentprovider

I have the code where I want catch all the contacts in the 
cellphone. It works perfectly but I'm having a problem performance . 
When I open the application a listview will be loaded with contacts (name, photo and numbers) and here is the 
problem! The listview takes so much time to load (between 5 and 8 
seconds). I have only 75 contacts here. I can't see where is the 
problem but I believe that someone here can help me.

Thanks...

My Code:
http://pastebin.com/zJrMknVg

Comment: Check this:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7299570/android-loading-contacts-is-too-slow

Comment: running the loading of contacts on main thread? You should be implementing a ViewHolder pattern for the loading of the list items...

Comment: THanks t0mm13b, I don't know ViewHolder pattern yet. I'll take a look, thanks!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How the user **Shijing Lv** said, there's in this thread a good solution for to do what I wanted.
Maybe this is the best solution for load images on listview, lazyLoad.

Here is the complete code:
https://github.com/thest1/LazyList

Thanks a lot for all help!